# Creating tree models in qt and data mapping

Tags: c++, qt, model, tree

I have looked through the qt docs at the tree model examples. I am struggling at how to  map my data structure to the model.

I have an array of mystructs which I would like to display in a tree, could someone offer any help on how to do this. The structure is shown below

```
struct mystruct{
    int id;
    float val;
    struct settings{
            QString setting_1;
            QString setting_2;
            bool on;
    };
};
```

I am trying to fit this structure into the qt simpletreemodel example.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to interact a lot with your struct from the tree view ? If not, I am not that sure you should go into the view/model for simple object like that. You may consider to stick with `QTreeWidget` and `QTreeWidgetItems` ...

Comment: yes , I need to ineract with the view

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

Implement the tree as a `QTreeWidget`

```
class YourTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
public:
    ...
    //reimplement useful stuff of the QTreeWidget 
    //like onItemClicked(...)
};
```

Then implement items binded to a `mystruct` instance

```
class mystruct;
class YourTreeWidgetItem : public QTreeWidgetItem
{
public:
    YourTreeWidgetItem(mystruct*);
    mystruct* getData() { return data;}
private:
    mystruct* data;
}
```

Later on create one `YourTreeWidget`, and add one item for each of the `mystruct` instance your have in your array.
Don't forget to format your `QTreeWidget` correctly according to the data you put in your items.

```
setHeaderLabels( QStringList() << "Column 1" << "Column 2");
...
```

Again it a simple solution, but I think your can do complexe stuff with that.

NOTE: when I said

> Do you have to interact *a lot* with struct

I meant do you need custom selection, custom edition, custom display ...

Comment: thanks for your time vince, and yes the tree model will be used by a number of differnt views